# React, can't select the first option of <select>

Tags: select, reactjs, jsx

I render a `<select>` box in react from an array. My array looks like this:

```
options: [
    {"id":1,"name":"Option1"},
    {"id":2,"name":"Option2"},
    {"id":3,"name":"Option3"}
    ];
```

I `map` the array and find all the options, then I render the options inside the `map`. However I'm able to select whatever option from the select, except the first one.

Here's my select:

```
<select
    className="form-control"
    name={this.props.name}
    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
    {(Array.isArray(this.props.options) && this.props.options.length > 0) ? this.props.options.map(option => {
        return (
            <option key={option.id} value={option.id}>{option.name}</option>
        )
    }) : (<option>No Options Found</option>)}
</select>
```

How do I do it, to be able to select the first option as well? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your first option is selected by default. If you want - you can create an empty option and after that you can select first option.

```
render() {
    const options = this.props.options.map(option =>
      <option key={option.id} value={option.id}>{option.name}</option>
    )

    return (
      <select
        className="form-control"
        name={this.props.name}
        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
      >
        <option value="">Select option</option>
        {options}
      </select>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Are there other ways without a empty options?

Answer (score 0):

add a default line before your options

```
<option>select size</option>
quickview_product.map(itm => <option value={itm.label}>{itm.label}</option>)
```